# get DB values on bootstrap modal with update button

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

[This is HTML page of showing placements table values with the edit button for each table row...values are retrieved from database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ajcB3.png)

```
$sql = 'SELECT * 
                  FROM placements';
          $statement = $con->prepare($sql);
          $statement->execute();
          $result = $statement->get_result();
          $placements = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
          $result->close();
          $statement->close();
          $con->close();
```

above code php which is data from placements:

```
 <tbody>
 <?php if ($placements) {
                    foreach ($placements as $placement) {
                        $id = $placement['id'];
                        $name = $placement['name'];
                        $eligibility = $placement['eligibility'];
                        $backlogs = $placement['backlogs'];
                        $rounds = $placement['rounds'];
                        $round1 = $placement['round1'];
                        $round2 = $placement['round2'];
                        $round3 = $placement['round3'];
                        $round4 = $placement['round4'];
                        $venu = $placement['venu'];
                        $date = $placement['date'];
                        ?>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $name; ?></a></td>
    <td><?php echo $eligibility; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $backlogs; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $rounds; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $round1; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $round2; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $round3; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $round4; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $venu; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $date; ?></td>
    <td><button type="button" id="editButton" name="editButton" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editModal">Edit</button>
  </td>
  </tr>
  <?php 
      }
   }
     else {
        ?>
          <tr>
              <td colspan="10">
                  - No placements found -
              </td>
          </tr>
          <?php
            }
          }
        ?>
        </tbody>
```

[this is the output of modal with retrive values from db and showing..when click the edit button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ElbDx.png)

Below code is for showing bootstrap modal....

```
<div class="modal fade" id="editModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">

        <!-- Modal Header -->
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="editModalLabel">Edit</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        </div>

        <!-- Modal body -->
        <div class="modal-body">

          <div class="modal-messages"></div>
          <form enctype="multipart/form-data">
          <input type="hidden" id="placementId" name="placementId">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name">Placement Name:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control disabled-on-error" id="name" name="name" required="">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="elig">Eligibility:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control disabled-on-error" id="elig" name="elig">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="backLogs">Backlogs:</label>
            <select class="form-control disabled-on-error" id="backLogs" name="backLogs">
                  <option value="No Backlogs" id="noBacklogs">No Backlogs</option>
                  <option value="<= 2 Backlogs" id="less2Backlogs"><= 2 Backlogs</option>
                  <option value=" > 2 Backlogs" id="greater2Backlogs"> 2 Backlogs</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="rownds">Rounds:</label>
            <select class="form-control disabled-on-error" id="rownds" name="rownds" onchange="change();" required="">
                  <option value="1" id="optionOne">1</option>
                  <option value="2" id="optionTwo">2</option>
                  <option value="3" id="optionThree">3</option>
                  <option value="4" id="optionFour">4</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group" id="dropbox"></div>
          <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="location">Interview Venu Location:</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control disabled-on-error" id="location" name="location">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
                  <label >Interview Date:</label>
                  <input class="form-control disabled-on-error" type="date" id="date" name="date" name="InterviewTime">
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
                <button type="button" id="updateButton" name="updateButton" value="update" class="btn btn-primary disabled-on-error">Update</button>
          </div>
        </form>
        </div>

        <!-- Modal footer -->
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

the below ajax code is to get placement values and showing on bootstrap modal.....also update edited values to store on the db.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
                $('#editModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
                    var modal = $(this);
                    // Extract the placement id from the modal triggering button.
                    var editButton = $(event.relatedTarget);
                    var placementId = editButton.val();

                    // Set the placement id in the modal (read prior to update operation).
                    modal.find('#placementId').val(placementId);

                    // Fetch the placement details and update the modal's content with them.
                    $.ajax({
                        method: 'post',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        url: 'get-placements.php',
                        data: {
                            'placementId': placementId
                        },
                        success: function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                            modal.find('.modal-title').text('Edit Placement ' + response.name);
                            modal.find('#name').val(response.name);
                            modal.find('#elig').val(response.eligibility);

                            switch (response.backlogs) {
                                case 'No Backlogs':
                                    modal.find('#noBacklogs').prop('selected', true);
                                    break;
                                case '<= 2 Backlogs': // No break.
                                    modal.find('#less2Backlogs').prop('selected', true);
                                    break;
                                case ' > 2 Backlogs': // No break.
                                    modal.find('#greater2Backlogs').prop('selected', true);
                                    break;
                            }

                            switch (response.rounds) {
                                case 1:
                                    modal.find('#optionOne').prop('selected', true);
                                    break;
                                case 2: // No break.
                                    modal.find('#optionTwo').prop('selected', true);
                                    break;
                                case 3: // No break.
                                    modal.find('#optionThree').prop('selected', true);
                                    break;
                                case 4: // No break.
                                    modal.find('#optionFour').prop('selected', true);
                                    break;
                            }

                            modal.find('#location').val(response.venu);
                            modal.find('#date').val(response.date);
                        },
                        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                            /*
                             * If the status code of the response is a custom one, defined by 
                             * the developer - here 420, then the corresponding error message 
                             * is displayed. Otherwise, the displayed message will be a general 
                             * user-friendly one - so, that no system-related infos will be shown.
                             */
                            var message = (jqXHR.status === 420)
                                    ? jqXHR.statusText
                                    : 'An error occurred during your request. Please try again.';

                            displayModalAlert(modal, 'danger', message);
                            disableModalControls(modal);
                        },
                        complete: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
                            //...
                        }
                    });
                });

                /*
                 * Re-enable the disabled controls on modal hide.
                 */
                $('#editModal').on('hide.bs.modal', function (event) {
                    var modal = $(this);

                    removeModalAlerts(modal);
                    enableModalControls(modal);
                });

                /*
                 * Update the user with the user input values.
                 */
                 $('#updateButton').on('click', function (event) {
                    var modal = $('#editModal');

                    removeModalAlerts(modal);

                    $.ajax({
                        method: 'post',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        url: 'update-placement.php',
                        data: {
                            'placementId': modal.find('#placementId').val(),
                            'name': modal.find('#name').val(),
                            'elig': modal.find('#elig').val(),
                            'backLogs': modal.find('input[name="backLogs"]:selected').val(),
                            'rownds': modal.find('input[name="rownds"]:selected').val(),
                            'rownd1': modal.find('input[name="rownd1"]:selected').val(),
                            'rownd2': modal.find('input[name="rownd2"]:selected').val(),
                            'rownd3': modal.find('input[name="rownd3"]:selected').val(),
                            'rownd4': modal.find('input[name="rownd4"]:selected').val(),
                            'venu': modal.find('#location').val(),
                            'date': modal.find('#date').val()
                        },
                        success: function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                            displayModalAlert(modal, 'success', response);
                        },
                        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                            /*
                             * If the status code of the response is a custom one, defined by 
                             * the developer - here 420, then the corresponding error message 
                             * is displayed. Otherwise, the displayed message will be a general 
                             * user-friendly one - so, that no system-related infos will be shown.
                             */
                            var message = (jqXHR.status === 420)
                                    ? jqXHR.statusText
                                    : 'An error occurred during your request. Please try again.';

                            displayModalAlert(modal, 'danger', message);
                        },
                        complete: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
                            //...
                        }
                    });
                });

            });    
            /**
             * Display a bootstrap alert in the modal.
             * 
             * @param modal object The modal object.
             * @param type string Type of alert (success|info|warning|danger).
             * @param message string Alert message.
             * @return void
             */
            function displayModalAlert(modal, type, message) {
                modal.find('.modal-messages').html(getAlert(type, message));
            }

            /**
             * Remove any bootstrap alert from the modal.
             * 
             * @param modal object The modal object.
             * @return void
             */
            function removeModalAlerts(modal) {
                modal.find('.modal-messages').html('');
            }

            /**
             * Disable predefined modal controls.
             * 
             * @param modal object The modal object.
             * @return void
             */
            function disableModalControls(modal) {
                modal.find('.disabled-on-error')
                        .prop('disabled', true)
                        .addClass('disabled')
                        .css({
                            'cursor': 'not-allowed'
                        });
            }

            /**
             * Enable predefined modal controls.
             * 
             * @param modal object The modal object.
             * @return void
             */
            function enableModalControls(modal) {
                modal.find('.disabled-on-error')
                        .prop('disabled', false)
                        .removeClass('disabled')
                        .css({
                            'cursor': 'auto'
                        });
            }

            /**
             * Get a bootstrap alert.
             * 
             * @param type string Type of alert (success|info|warning|danger).
             * @param message string Alert message.
             * @return string The bootstrap alert.
             */
            function getAlert(type, message) {
                return '<div class="alert alert-' + type + ' alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">'
                        + '<span>' + message + '</span>'
                        + '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">'
                        + '<span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>'
                        + '</button>'
                        + '</div>';
            }
</script>
```

this below code is get-placements.php...

```
<?php

require_once('dbconfig/config.php');
if (!isset($_POST['placementId']) || empty($_POST['placementId'])) {

    header('HTTP/1.1 420 No placement specified.');
    exit();
}

$placementId = $_POST['placementId'];

$sql = 'SELECT * 
        FROM placements
        WHERE id = ?
        LIMIT 1';

$statement = $con->prepare($sql);

$statement->bind_param('i', $placementId);

$statement->execute();
$result = $statement->get_result();
$placement = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

if (!isset($placement)) {
    header('HTTP/1.1 420 No placement found by the given criteria.');
    exit();
}

$result->close();
$statement->close();
$con->close();

echo json_encode($placement);
exit();
?>
```

[when i edit the values placement name google to microsoft and rounds 4 to 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ElbDx.png)

[when i select rounds 4 to 3 it display 3 select boxes with default values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j5jAj.png)

this is the java script code for showing select boxes based on selecting number of rounds...

```
function change() {
        var select = document.getElementById("rownds");
        var divv = document.getElementById("dropbox");
        var value = select.value;
        if (value == 1) {
            toAppend = "<label>Round 1:</label>&nbsp;<select class='form-control' id='OneRound'  name='rownd1'>&nbsp;<option value='WrittenTest'>WrittenTest</option>&nbsp;<option value='Technicalround1'>Technicalround1</option>&nbsp;<option value='Technicalround2'>Technicalround2</option>&nbsp;<option value='HR_Interview'>HR_Interview</option>&nbsp;</select>"; divv.innerHTML=toAppend; return;
            }
            if (value == 2) {
                toAppend = "<label>Round 1:</label>&nbsp;<select class='form-control' id='TwoRounds' name='rownd1'>&nbsp;<option value='WrittenTest'>WrittenTest</option>&nbsp;<option value='Technicalround1'>Technicalround1</option>&nbsp;<option value='Technicalround2'>Technicalround2</option>&nbsp;<option value='HR_Interview'>HR_Interview</option>&nbsp;</select>&nbsp;<label>Round 2:</label>&nbsp;<select class='form-control' id='TwoRounds' name='rownd2'>&nbsp;<option value='WrittenTest'>WrittenTest</option>&nbsp;<option value='Technicalround1' selected='selected'>Technicalround1</option>&nbsp;<option value='Technicalround2'>Technicalround2</option>&nbsp;<option value='HR_Interview'>HR_Interview</option>&nbsp;</select>";divv.innerHTML = toAppend;  return;
            }
            if (value == 3) {
                toAppend = "<label>Round 1:</label>&nbsp;<select class='form-control' id='ThreeRounds' name='rownd1'>&nbsp;<option value='WrittenTest'>WrittenTest</option>&nbsp;<option value='Technicalround1'>Technicalround1</option>&nbsp;<option value='Technicalround2'>Technicalround2</option>&nbsp;<option value='HR_Interview'>HR_Interview</option>&nbsp;</select>&nbsp;<label>Round 2:</label>&nbsp;<select class='form-control' id='ThreeRounds' name='rownd2'>&nbsp;<option value='WrittenTest'>WrittenTest</option>&nbsp;<option value='Technicalround1' selected='selected'>Technicalround1</option>&nbsp;<option value='Technicalround2'>Technicalround2</option>&nbsp;<option value='HR_Interview'>HR_Interview</option>&nbsp;</select>&nbsp;<label>Round 3:</label>&nbsp;<select class='form-control' id='ThreeRounds' name='rownd3'>&nbsp;<option value='WrittenTest'>WrittenTest</option>&nbsp;<option value='Technicalround1'>Technicalround1</option>&nbsp;<option value='Technicalround2'>Technicalround2</option>&nbsp;<option value='HR_Interview' selected='selected'>HR_Interview</option>&nbsp;</select>";divv.innerHTML = toAppend;  return;
            }
            if (value == 4) {
                toAppend = "<label>Round 1:</label>&nbsp;<select class='form-control' id='FourRounds' name='rownd1'>&nbsp;<option value='WrittenTest'>WrittenTest</option>&nbsp;<option value='Technicalround1'>Technicalround1</option>&nbsp;<option value='Technicalround2'>Technicalround2</option>&nbsp;<option value='HR_Interview'>HR_Interview</option>&nbsp;</select>&nbsp;<label>Round 2:</label>&nbsp;<select class='form-control' id='FourRounds' name='rownd2'>&nbsp;<option value='WrittenTest'>WrittenTest</option>&nbsp;<option value='Technicalround1' selected='selected'>Technicalround1</option>&nbsp;<option value='Technicalround2'>Technicalround2</option>&nbsp;<option value='HR_Interview'>HR_Interview</option>&nbsp;</select>&nbsp;<label>Round 3:</label>&nbsp;<select class='form-control' id='FourRounds' name='rownd3'>&nbsp;<option value='WrittenTest'>WrittenTest</option>&nbsp;<option value='Technicalround1'>Technicalround1</option>&nbsp;<option value='Technicalround2' selected='selected'>Technicalround2</option>&nbsp;<option value='HR_Interview'>HR_Interview</option>&nbsp;</select>&nbsp;<label>Round 4:</label>&nbsp;<select class='form-control' id='FourRounds' name='rownd4'>&nbsp;<option value='WrittenTest'>WrittenTest</option>&nbsp;<option value='Technicalround1'>Technicalround1</option>&nbsp;<option value='Technicalround2'>Technicalround2</option>&nbsp;<option value='HR_Interview' selected='selected'>HR_Interview</option>&nbsp;</select>";divv.innerHTML = toAppend;  return;

            }
}
```

my intend is to display the select boxes when click on the edit button...example for placement name 'google' have 4 rounds when click on google row edit button it shows on modal with all values except not showing 4 select boxes which are based on 4 rounds on modal....but it is not working.

[it shows error when click on button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dV6JR.png)

this below code update-placement.php

```
 <?php
    require_once('dbconfig/config.php');
if (!isset($_POST['placementId']) || empty($_POST['placementId'])) {
    header('HTTP/1.1 420 No user specified.');
    exit();
} 
if (!isset($_POST['name']) || empty($_POST['name'])) {
    header('HTTP/1.1 420 Please provide the name.');
    exit();
} 
      $placementId = $_POST['placementId'];
      $name = $_POST['name'];
      $eligibility = $_POST['elig'];
      $backlogs=$_POST['backLogs'];
      $rounds=$_POST['rownds'];

      if( isset($_POST["rownd1"]) && isset($_POST["rownd2"] ) && isset($_POST["rownd3"] ) && isset($_POST["rownd4"] ))
      {
          $round1=$_POST['rownd1'];
          $round2=$_POST['rownd2'];
          $round3=$_POST['rownd3'];
          $round4=$_POST['rownd4'];
      }
      elseif (isset($_POST["rownd1"]) && isset($_POST["rownd2"] ) && isset($_POST["rownd3"] )) {
          $round1=$_POST['rownd1'];
          $round2=$_POST['rownd2'];
          $round3=$_POST['rownd3'];
          $round4=NULL;
      }
      elseif (isset($_POST["rownd1"]) && isset($_POST["rownd2"] )) {
          $round1=$_POST['rownd1'];
          $round2=$_POST['rownd2'];
          $round3=NULL;
          $round4=NULL;
      }
      elseif (isset($_POST["rownd1"]))
      {
          $round1=$_POST['rownd1'];
          $round2=NULL;
          $round3=NULL;
          $round4=NULL;
      }

      $venu=$_POST['location'];
      $date=$_POST['date'];

      $query = 'UPDATE placements 
        SET 
            id = ?;
            name = ?,
            eligibility = ?,
            backlogs = ?,
            rounds = ?,
            round1 = ?,
            round2 = ?,
            round3 = ?,
            round4 = ?,
            venu = ?,
            date = ? 
        WHERE id = ?';
$statement = $con->prepare($sql);

$statement->bind_param('isssissssssi', $placementId, $name, $eligibility, $backlogs, $rounds, $round1, $round2, $round3, $round4, $venu, $date, $placementId);

$statement->execute();

$affectedRows = $con->affected_rows;

$statement->close();
$con->close();

if ($affectedRows === -1) {
    header('HTTP/1.1 420 An error occurred during your request. Please try again.');
    exit();
} else {
    echo json_encode('User data successfully saved.');
    exit();
}
?>
```

when i click on update button in modal it shows error...this is my problem....please help me.